# Custom UIView iOS

Tags: xcode, ios

Приветствую. У меня возникла проблема, у меня есть ViewController, на нем расположена View 
http://cs620425.vk.me/v620425086/5231/i7Xjvb9AUWQ.jpg
Создал новый класс наследник UIView  связал их(как я понял) 
http://cs620425.vk.me/v620425086/5238/2uhzTh3VY00.jpg
Но почему-то при взаимодействии с View в классе ничего не вызывается (ни один BreakPoint не сработал)
Может я что-то упускаю?

вот файл DOColorView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DOColorChange.h"

@interface DOColorView : UIView <DOColorChange, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField* tfRed;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField* tfGreen;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField* tfBlue;

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView* colorView;

@end
```

DOColorView.m
    //
    //  DOColorView.m
    //  test3
    //
    //  Created by DaskOFF on 19.04.14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 DaskOFF. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#import "DOColorView.h"

@implementation DOColorView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.tfRed.text = @"0";
        self.tfGreen.text = @"0";
        self.tfBlue.text = @"0";

        self.tfRed.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Protocol DOColorChange
-(UIView *)changeView:(UIView *)View
            withColor:(UIColor *)Color {
    View.tintColor = Color;
    return View;
}

#pragma mark - Protocol UITextFieldDelegate
//Нажатие на кнопке Return клавиатуры
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([self.tfRed isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.tfRed resignFirstResponder];
        [self.tfGreen becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if ([self.tfGreen isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.tfGreen resignFirstResponder];
        [self.tfBlue becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if ([self.tfBlue isFirstResponder]) {
        [self.tfBlue resignFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}

//Ввод в UITextField
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == self.tfRed || textField == self.tfGreen || textField == self.tfBlue) {
        ;
    }
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Поставьте брекпоинт на строчке  self.tfRed.delegate = self; 
Во-первых втанет ли он на него?
Во-вторых если встанет, то проверьте `self.tfRed` на nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При "рождении" view c XIB/Storyboard вызывается не

`- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`

a

`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`

Вынесите всю инициализацию в этот метод. А еще лучше напишите что-то типа

```
- (void) commonInit {
    self.tfRed.text = @"0";
    self.tfGreen.text = @"0";
    self.tfBlue.text = @"0";

    self.tfRed.delegate = self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
 }

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
     self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
     if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
     }
     return self;
 }
```

Comment: Может лучше во `ViewDidLoad` тогда уж сто пудов self.tfRed будет в памяти, чтоб делегат прикрутить.

Comment: @Bimawa дак речь же о сабклассе UIView а не UIViewController.

Comment: @szarajewski точная поправка. видимо уже сплю :) В общем вижу истину в Вашем ответе

Comment: так мне надо вручную вызывать [myColorView init], если я создал IBOutlet на свой View во ViewController? 

Если так, то таким образом работает (но правильно ли это?), но тогда возникает проблема в том, вто нажатие по кнопке "ввод" на клавиатуре переводит FirsResponse только с поля R в поле G, а в полях G и B не реагирует?

Скажите какие именно файлы кинуть?

Comment: Как вариант, проверьте проперти делегатов, обычно конфликты бывают из за того что название у них одинаковое - `delegate`

Answer (score 0):

Думаю дело в том что ваши IBOutlet'ы в классе никак не связаны с теми компонентами что вы накидали на вид на форме или вы нам не показали их просто. Попробуйте привязать их